# Unknown Symbols in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

I accidentally pressed a key in the eclipse ide and these symbols were created by themselves. how can i restore it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNZvM.png)

Comment: Those are just paragraph indicators. Look at buttons on toolbar, one of them toogles it

Comment: Look for the button with the same symbol `¶` on the tool bar